# Match array elements/element (at least one) from another array in mongoose

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose

Lets say in my database :

```
{
  domains:[A, B, C],
  id: 1
},
{
  domains:[B, C],
  id: 2
},
{
  domains:[A],
  id: 3
},
{
  domains:[B, D],
  id: 4
}
```

I want to search query like `domains: [A, D]`. Basically i want to match at least one element not for all element.

My expecting answer is

```
{
  domains:[A, B, C],
  id: 1
},
{
  domains:[A],
  id: 3
},
{
  domains:[B, D],
  id: 4
}
```

Cause A and D(at least one) are found into this objects.

I want to retrieve questions, which matches the at least one topics?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) operator in this way:

```
yourModel.find({
  "domains": {
    "$in": [
      "A",
      "D"
    ]
  }
})
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/SKkiqtLilzI)

Comment: Works well. Thanks a lot J.F.

Comment: J.F. I updated my question. I added a second question.Can you answer the question?